# __str__ meet RecursionError when the class has a Descriptor

Tags: python

The code is shown as below. I just know the reason for the `RecursionError` is that `student.age` called `__get__` in `Descriptor` with an infinite loop. However, I neither know the root-cause nor the solution.

How could I go about this?

```
class Descriptor(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        print(f"get::instance={instance}, owner={owner}")
        if instance is None:
            pass
        return instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print(f"set::instance={instance}, value={value}")
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        print(f"delete::instance={instance}")
        del instance.__dict__[self.name]

class Student(object):
    name = Descriptor("name")
    school = Descriptor("school")

    def __init__(self, name, school, age):
        self.name = name
        self.school = school
        self.age = age

    # self.school will call Descriptor.__get__(student, Student)，
    # so nfinite loop？
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Student::name={self.name}, school={self.school}, age={self.age}"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = Student("Yannick", "HUST", "30")
    print(s.age)
```

Comment: in `__set__` you _print_ the instance.  Your instance's `__str__` tries to `__get__` some of the attributes, but that invokes another call to `print` (and `__str__`) and the cycle repeats.  If you remove the `print` statements (or change you `__str__` to not call the descriptors), then it should be OK (from what I can see)

Comment: @mgilson Thanks a lot. I really got it and you're right. I will close this issue.

Comment: @mgilson - that is the correct answer here - do you care posting it as such?

Comment: @Yannick : also - no need to "close" - you made a question - it will get a valid answer, and you accept it. People gain reputation points, and everyone is happy. That is the way things work around here. Also, welcome!

Comment: @jsbueno Oh.. got it. You're right, I'm new here, Also, hope I can learn and improve myself more here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- In `__set__` you print the instance.
- Your instance's `__str__` tries to `__get__` some of the attributes
- that invokes another call to `print`

  - which implicitly calls (and `__str__`)

and the cycle repeats.

If you remove the `print` functions (or change your `__str__` to not call the descriptors), then it should be OK.